# C++ MinGW x64 Debugging - value of std::string doesn't display properly

Tags: c++, string, mingw-w64

I'm using CLion 1.0.3 with MinGW 64 to create my projects, and when I debug, my `std::string` variable displays (in the variables/watches panel) fine while in the scope of the `main` function, but as soon as I pass the variable to my class constructor, the value copied to the parameter displays *really* strangely. The value remains unchanged - I checked by attempting to `cout` the string, which outputs the same as the original - but the display in the variables panel appears to be a set of characters, most of which are represented by an escape sequence, that does not correspond to the `string` object at all.

In fact, the display appears to be reading the bytes that make up the string object (though I could be wrong), rather than the string that the object represents. It's better explained with an example:

int main()

```
int main() {
    string string1 = "test.txt"; //Debugger displays 'string1 = {std::string} "test.txt"' - normal.
    cout << string1 << endl; //Console displays 'text.txt' - normal.
    File f(string1); // <--- Passing to this constructor
    return 0;
}
```

File::File(std::string) - (Note that the first `File` is a namespace, the second is the class, and the third is the constructor)

```
Brad::API::File::File::File(std::string passed) {
    std::cout << passed << std::endl; // Outputs "test.txt" - normal
}
```

All is great as far as program function goes, except that when I tried to view the value of `passed`, it shows up as `passed = {std::string} "<\022;\000�yA\000��(\000\001\000\000\000\200�(\000�\023@\000�\016;\000/\000\000 ...(I removed ~54,000 more characters from here for the sake of readability)"...<error: Cannot access memory at address 0x294000>`

As mentioned, there was roughly 54,000 characters to show for an 8-character string, which makes me think that it might just be reading the memory and giving me the raw bytes.

I'm utterly confused as to why this might be happening, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you see this behaviour with another IDE (e.g. Qt Creator or Eclipse)?

Comment: @rubenvb Never seen it before, even in CLion. I've been using the same IDE and the same compiler since about 2 weeks after CLion was released, and I haven't had this issue until now.

Comment: so what changed? CLion update, toolchain update, ... ?

Comment: That's the thing.. Nothing, as far as I can tell. Last CLion update was a while ago, but it seems to me that this would be a compiler issue, since (correct me if I'm wrong) the IDE only uses the compiler's debugging utilities. I haven't touched my compiler either.

Comment: I'd take this to the CLion developers. They would be infinitely more helpful than anyone browsing SO and reading your quesstion. At least I hope so.

Comment: That's a good point. Just wasn't sure if someone had a similar issue, or could make a prediction as to what might be happening.

Comment: After some playing around, I managed to fix the issue by passing the std::string as a reference, rather than as a value.